# How to Successfully add the MenuBar with the Buttons in place?

Tags: java, menu

This is my code, but the MenuBar Refuses to show up. How do I add the menu bar to get it to pull up? The only thing that shows up is the buttons. If I add something, the frame will refuse to show the menu. Please tell me what I did wrong, thanks in advance.

```
import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.JMenu;
    import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
    import javax.swing.JMenuItem;


    public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {


    public MyFrame() {

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyFrame");


            this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());



            JButton ExitBtn = new JButton();

            ExitBtn.setText("Exit");
            ExitBtn.addActionListener(this);
            JButton Find = new JButton("Find");
            JButton Clear = new JButton("Clear");
            // add buttons to frame

            add(ExitBtn);

            add(Find);
            add(Clear);



     JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
           JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
            menuBar.add(menu);
            JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Exit");
            menu.add(item);


        }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    System.exit(0);
    //ExitBtn.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyFrame();
    MyFrame mf = new MyFrame();
    mf.pack();
    mf.setSize(800, 650);
    mf.setVisible(true);
    mf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added your `JMenuBar` to the `JFrame` and hence it won't show. Add it to your `JFrame` just as you would add other `JComponent`s :)

Answer (score 0):

Just call [`setJMenuBar()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setJMenuBar%28javax.swing.JMenuBar%29) in the MyFrame constructor. Like so:

```
setJMenuBar(menuBar);
```

Also this isn't related to your original question but you should probably remove the first `new MyFrame();` from your main method. It's unnecessary since you're already creating another instance of your GUI directly below that.